# ¿Por qué window.open('index.html', '_self'); no está funcionando?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy programando un sitio web que consta de dos páginas.

La primera página es una ventana con un botón que ejecuta el siguiente script:

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Ingrese la clave',' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1) 
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "aqui va la clave que debe ingresar el usuario") {
           alert('Bienvenido!');
           window.open('index.html');
           break;
        } 
        testV+=1;
        var pass1 = 
        prompt('Acceso Denegado - Clave incorrecta. Por favor intente nuevamente.','Clave');
    }
   if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
      history.go(-1);
      return " ";
   } 
</SCRIPT>
```

Esto me funciona de maravilla, sin embargo, cuando el usuario introduce la clave correcta, abre la página **index.html** una **ventana nueva** y necesito que index.html se abra en **la misma ventana**.

Inicialmente intenté modificando la línea `window.open('index.html');`

para que quedara así: `window.open('index.html', '_self');` (lo que en teoría debería funcionar), pero esto no me ha funcionado.

1. **¿Por qué** no me está funcionando?
2. **¿Cómo** hago que sí funcione?

Por si es relevante: estoy intentando que esto funcione en **Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox e Internet Explorer**.

Comment: _sin embargo, cuando el usuario introduce la clave correcta, abre una ventana nueva y necesito que se abra en la misma ventana_  ¿que se abra **qué** en la misma ventana?  _Nota:_ Para identar el código es mejor, una vez escrito seleccionar todo y darle click al botón **`{   }`** arriba. Precisamente, a **algunos `if` parece que le faltan llaves de apertura o de cierre: `{   }`**

Comment: que se abra la _otra_ página (index.html)

Comment: En primer lugar revisa la apertura-cierre de llaves en los bloques, veo algún  if sin llave de apertura  `{`

Comment: @A.Cedano el último if solo aplica a `history.go`. El return siempre se ejecutará.

Comment: Todas las llaves `{ }` están completas. Como dije, el código me ha funcionado perfecto excepto por el detalle que me abre una ventana nueva en lugar de abrir la página en la misma ventana.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema. Haciendo literalmente copy-paste de tu código y añadiendo `_self`, funciona como se espera.

Comment: Probado en IE 11, Edge y Chrome con 100% de éxito. Procedo a votar para cerrar porque «no se puede reproducir» tu problema.

Comment: tendrá algo que ver con la versión de chrome que estoy usando? es la última disponible para **windows xp** y no se puede actualizar

Comment: No lo creo, todo navegador, aún IE 8 tiene soporte para window.open, pero no estoy seguro si navegadores viejos interpretan `_self` correctamente. Sería cuestión que pruebes en un equipo más moderno.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con location href de javascript en lugar de window open.

ejemplo:

```
location.href = "index.html";
```

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo y no hace nada :/ literalmente, nada. Ingreso la clave correcta y me deja en la misma pagina de login (la pagina con el boton)

Comment: Probablemente tengas bloqueado en tu navegador las ventanas emergentes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/owa1zej4/